# Installation File Name Format Best Practice

Tags: windows, installation, filenames

I was reading the post [Installation file names in Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469270/installation-file-names-in-windows-vista) when I thought about Installation File Names. I'm a addicted software downloader, and frequently I've got installation names like "setup.exe" or "install.exe", that says nothing about the program to be installed.

I think that an installation file must be like:

**Install[ProgramName][ProgramVersion][Platform].[exe|msi|etc]**


or

**[ProgramName][ProgramVersion][Platform].Setup.[exe|msi|etc]**

What your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is entirely programming-related... but installer files are usually meant to be transient. You download them, run them, and delete them. (Or at least, I think most people do) So it doesn't matter much what the filename is.

I don't think there's any reason *not* to give the installer a descriptive name... but I certainly wouldn't say it "must" have one.

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer descriptive install file names.  Sometimes, you want an emergency 'restore' disk to get a machine up and running even without internet connectivity.  When all your installs are named "setup.exe", you either have to rename them all, or create a directory with a descriptive name for each one.

An example of where such a disk would have been really handy was when I took my brand new laptop in to work to use while I upgraded my desktop to Vista 64, and then Windows 7.  I only have one wired LAN point, so my laptop needed a wireless connection for internet access, to download my installs.  I had to download them all on my desktop, and then transfer by flash drive to my laptop.  Very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

For CD-Rom based installation, I'd suggest sticking with `SETUP.EXE` which helps with autorun detecting software to install from the disk.

For downloadable files, just add the appropriate manifest to the EXE and Vista won't have a problem with it. I'd suggest something semi-descriptive, but there's no need to go into great detail unless it's something like hardware drivers that a person may archive off for reuse, otherwise the file name is confusing to non-technical people.